# GridView doesn't refresh

Tags: c#, aspxgridview

I have an aspx page with a gridview "DGV_LISTEJOURS" and an iframe "FR_MODIFPERIODE".

My frame is dynamic with other aspx pages.

In pages which are in the frame I have buttons which update a database. At the end or while working I want to refresh gridview

Code which calls an example of page in frame

```
FR_MODIFPERIODE.Attributes["src"] = "ModifPeriode_Heures.aspx?date="+ xligne.Cells[2].Text + " (Id:" + xligne.Cells[1].Text + ")&Debut="+ xligne.Cells[3].Text+"&Fin="+ xligne.Cells[4].Text;
```

In the button which updates in the database I have this code

```
GestionDisposV2.refreshdgvext(xidperiode);
```

`GestionDisposV2` is the page which has the gridview and the iframe

this is the code to refresh

```
public static void refreshdgvext(int xidperiode)
{
    DataTable xdttempo = new DataTable();
    DataRow xlignedttempo = null;
    GridView xdgv = (GridView)xpage.FindControl("DGV_LISTEJOURS");
    //on rempli la table des jours depuis la table
    DataTable xlistedispo_jours = BibliothequeClasses.GestionBDD.LectureBdd("select * from bddispos_periodesjours where idbddispos_periodes_int = '" + xidperiode + "';", BibliothequeClasses.Variables.xretourbddsiok);
    xdttempo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("AMPOULE", typeof(string)));
    xdttempo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(string)));
    xdttempo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("JOUR", typeof(string)));
    xdttempo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("DEBUTDISPO", typeof(string)));
    xdttempo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FINDISPO", typeof(string)));
    xdttempo.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("BTNACTIVER", typeof(string)));
    DateTime xjour;

    //stockage dans la dt tempo
    foreach (DataRow xdispo_jours in xlistedispo_jours.Rows)
    {
        xjour = DateTime.Parse(xdispo_jours["dateperiode_da"].ToString());
        xlignedttempo = xdttempo.NewRow();
        if (int.Parse(xdispo_jours["dateperiode_actif_bo"].ToString()) == 1)
        {
            xlignedttempo["AMPOULE"] = "~/Images/icones/icons8-lumière-allumée-48.png";
            xlignedttempo["BTNACTIVER"] = "Desactiver";
        }
        else
        {
            xlignedttempo["AMPOULE"] = "~/Images/icones/icons8-lumière-éteinte-48.png";
            xlignedttempo["BTNACTIVER"] = "Activer";
        }
        xlignedttempo["ID"] = int.Parse(xdispo_jours["idbddispos_periodesjours_int"].ToString());
        xlignedttempo["JOUR"] = BibliothequeClasses.GestionDate_Heure.jour_jour_date(xjour) + "/" + BibliothequeClasses.GestionDate_Heure.mois_jour_date(xjour) + "/" + BibliothequeClasses.GestionDate_Heure.annee_jour_date(xjour);
        xlignedttempo["DEBUTDISPO"] = xdispo_jours["heuredebut_vc"].ToString();
        xlignedttempo["FINDISPO"] = xdispo_jours["heurefin_vc"].ToString();
        xdttempo.Rows.Add(xlignedttempo);
    }
    //deversement dans la dgv
    xdgv.DataSource = xdttempo;
    xdgv.DataBind();
}
```

the "xpage" is in load of `GestionDisposV2`

```
public static Page xpage;
xpage = this.Page;
```

My problem is GridView Doesn't refresh, do you have an idea why?